# Overloading "+=" operator: c+=a_times_b works, but c+=a*b does not?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, in-place, compound-assignment

I have two classes A and B. The product A*B should be of type B.
Since variables of type B will occupy great amounts of memory, I need to avoid operations like `B_1 = B_1 + (A_1 * B_2)`, where `(A_1 * B_2)` would be temporarily allocated. In other words, I need `B_1 += A_1 * B_2`.

I have tried this:

```
struct A {
    int a;
};

struct B {
    double b[size];

    void operator += (pair<A*, B*> & lhsA_times_rhsB){
        A & lhsA = *lhsA_times_rhsB.first;
        B & rhsB = *lhsA_times_rhsB.second;

        b[lhsA.a] += rhsB.b[lhsA.a];
    }
};

inline pair<A*, B*> operator*( A& lhsA,  B& rhsB){
    return make_pair(&lhsA, &rhsB);
};

int main(){
    A A_in;
    B B_in, B_out;

    pair<A*, B*> product = A_in*B_in;

    B_out += product;    //this works!
    B_out += A_in*B_in;  //doesn't work!? (Compiler: "No viable overloaded '+='")

    return 0;
}
```

1. Why is `B_out += product` okay but `B_out += A_in * B_in` is not?
2. Is there a better way to implement the `+=`-operator for this use? Maybe without defining the helper object `pair<A*, B*>`?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear *error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'std::pair<A*, B*>&' to an rvalue of type 'std::pair<A*, B*>'*

Comment: @NathanOliver I was using clang, which just gave me "no viable overloaded '+='" and "candidate function not viable: expects an l-value for 1st argument". Next time I will ask for the opinion of gcc too :)

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that you're creating a temporary `pair<A*, B*>` when you multiply `A_in*B_in`

The signature for your `operator+=` is

```
 void operator += (pair<A*, B*> & lhsA_times_rhsB)
```

You cannot create a non-const reference from a temporary. The compiler<sup>*</sup> (gcc) tells you as much:

> error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type '`std::pair<A*, B*>&`' to an rvalue of type '`std::pair<A*, B*>`'

#### How to read the error message:

The 'rvalue' is your temporary `pair<A*, B*>` returned from `operator*`, and the 'non-const lvalue reference' is the targeted `pair<A*, B*>&`

#### Solution:

Change `operator+=` to use a const reference instead:

```
void operator += (const pair<A*, B*>& lhsA_times_rhsB)
```

You do not appear to need to modify `lhsA_times_rhsB`, so you should prefer constness.

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/OpEPmwm52kSL6o8b)

<sup>*Clang's error message is actually less informative here because it gets broken into two. The first one is "error: no viable overloaded '+='", and the second one is only slightly more descriptive: "candidate function not viable: expects an l-value for 1st argument"</sup>